# How to Join to "Other" row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have two tables. One holds `Objects` and the other holds `Settings` about each object. Not all of the rows in the `Objects` table have a corresponding row in the `Settings` table. There is a special row in the `Settings` table that is supposed to be used for the "Other" objects.

How can I create a join between `Objects` and `Settings` such that I get the given setting if there is one or the "Other" setting if there isn't?

For example consider the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE #Objects (Code nvarchar(20) not null);
CREATE TABLE #Settings (Code nvarchar(20) not null, Value int not null);

INSERT INTO #Objects
VALUES
    ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('D')

INSERT INTO #Settings
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 2),
    ('C', 3),
    ('Other', 4)

SELECT 
    #Objects.Code,
    #Settings.Value 
FROM
    #Objects
    JOIN #Settings
        ON #Objects.Code = #Settings.Code
        OR #Settings.Code = 'Other'

DROP TABLE #Settings, #Objects
```

I'm wanting to get this:

```
Code | Value
---- | -----
A    | 1
B    | 2
D    | 4
```

What I'm actually getting is:

```
Code  | Value
----- | -----
A     | 1
A     | 4
B     | 2
B     | 4
D     | 4
```

Comment: I'm curious to see execution plans on each of the four working answers so far against real data from reasonably-sized and indexed tables. For the sample data, it probably gives the same or similar plan to all of the answers, and any differences would be too small to measure.

Comment: Now five working answers :) But I'm hesitant to vote for any of them without seeing a plan.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn sadly my performance requirement is not tight ('runs in under half an hour on a 1000 or so objects'), but my development budget is ('haven't you finished it yet, if not why not?'). So I guess query plans on big data will have to wait for another day. I agree it would be nice to do the analysis though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an `APPLY`:

```
SELECT o.Code, s.Value
FROM #Objects o
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM #Settings s 
    WHERE s.Code = o.Code or s.Code = 'Other' 
    ORDER BY case when s.Code = o.Code then 0 else 1 end
) s
```

---

For fun: a hybrid from answers by [Gurv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816787/3043), [jyao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816874/3043) and [SqlZim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816424/3043), which are all variations on the same basic theme:

```
SELECT o.Code, s2.Value
FROM #Objects o
LEFT JOIN #Settings s1 on s1.Code = o.Code
INNER JOIN #Settings s2 on s2.Code = coalesce(s1.Code, 'Other')
```

So far, this approach (`LEFT JOIN` + the `INNER JOIN ON COALESCE()` ) is my favorite option.

Note that this only works if there can be only one Settings record per Object record. If that ever changes, the APPLY answer *still works*, but other answers here might not work.

Comment: I like this answer mostly because the problem I've got is actually a small part of something way more complex and I'm already using an APPLY.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `left join` to get `null` where `o.Code` has no match in `#Settings`
, and using [**`coalesce()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to return the designated replacement `value` 
from `#Settings` when `s.Value` is `null`.

You could use [**`isnull()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) instead of `coalesce`, the result would be the same in this instance.

I am not sure if this acceptable, but it returns the correct results:

```
select 
    o.Code
  , coalesce(s.Value,x.Value) as Value
from #Objects o
  left join #Settings s 
    on o.Code = s.Code
  cross join (
    select top 1 value
    from #Settings
    where Code = 'Other'
    ) x
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EBUG86037

returns:

```
+------+-------+
| Code | Value |
+------+-------+
| A    |     1 |
| B    |     2 |
| D    |     4 |
+------+-------+
```

---

In the form @RBarryYoung prefers:

```
select 
    o.Code
  , coalesce(s.Value,x.Value) as Value
from #Objects o
  left join #Settings s 
    on o.Code = s.Code
  inner join #Settings x
    on x.Code = 'Other'
```

This is more concise (saves you many [keystrokes](http://keysleft.com/)) and generates the same execution plan as my initial answer. Whether it is more or less clear about what it is doing is up to you, I like both.

Comment: Nice, though I'd prefer `inner join(..) on Code = 'Other'` to `cross join (.. where Code = 'Other')`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks for that, I updated my answer to include your alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If there is going to be one "Other" value then you can just do the `join` twice -  a `left join` and another one which is effectively a `cross join`:

```
select o.Code,
    coalesce(s.Value, s2.value) as value
from #Objects o
left join #Settings s on o.Code = s.Code
join #Settings s2 on s2.Code = 'Other'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use CTE to add an additional column [Alternative_code] for [#Object] table that has value "Other" for [Code] not existing in [#Settings]
and then using this CTE to join with #Settings table as shown below

```
; with c as (
    select alternative_Code = isnull(s.code, 'Other'), o.Code
    from #Objects o
    left join #Settings s
        on o.Code = s.Code)
select c.Code, s.value
from c
inner join #Settings s
on c.alternative_Code = s.Code
```

Comment: You can do this without the cte. Just join to settings twice and put a coalesce in the condition for the 2nd join.